# JavaScript: function with switch/case vs. overwriting the function

Tags: javascript, ajax, themes, switch-statement, overwrite

I've got a function that updates element sizes based upon the size of the browser:

`window.onresize = function() { setContentHeight(); }`

However, now that I've used AJAX to swap themes (changing the body's innerHTML,) this function needs to change.  The new themes have not only new images, but also entirely different layouts.  As such, the old onresize function simply messes up the page.  I've thought of two ways to fix this:

Method 1) Pass a parameter to a slightly modified function `setContentHeight(themeSelection);`, where the parameter is used in a switch/case statement.  Pro: A theme swap would merely change the value of the variable passed.  Con: `setContentHeight(themeSelection);` would include the code for all themes and be longer than it needed to be.

Method 2) Overwriting the function by eval'ing some script code parsed from the XMLHTTPRequest.  However, I have no idea how to get JS to modify an existing function or simply delete it and start a new one. Pro: The function would remain short  Con: I have no idea how to do it.

Which would you do, or would you do something else entirely?  If your answer is method 2, then could you provide a link on how it is done?  I have no problem doing most of the work myself, of course, but I could use some advice and an example of method #2 if it is the preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're changing the body's `innerHTML`, can't you also just add/remove a class? Or, better yet, change a global variable:

```
var current_theme = 'some_theme';

function loading_new_theme() {
    ...
    current_theme = 'new_theme';
}
```

Then you could have `setContentHeight` assign the height based on that global variable.

(Also: if you're not going to pass any arguments to `setContentHeight`, you could just do this:

```
window.onresize = setContentHeight;
```

)

Comment: I could add/remove a class, but I don't think that would stop the setContentHeight() function from messing up the dimensions of the objects.  I suppose that, since themeSelection is a global variable,  you are correct in saying that I don't have to pass it as a parameter, but nevertheless, the question of method #1 vs. #2 remains.  I'm going to implement it as switch/case unless someone convinces me otherwise, though.  I just figured I'd ask just in case an SO expert had a better idea.  :)

Comment: Not that this solves the original problem, but I found a great way to change my skin that doesn't involve re-uploading the entire body or using javascript to change classes: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml .   All I have to do is set up a CSS for each skin, and then just swap the CSS files.

Comment: @Michael If that's what you'll do, you should answer the question yourself and accept it.